# Like button with added confirm

Tags: debugging, facebook-like

Been adding a Like Button to all of my pages on my site, easy enough. Had a problem with the Text box that opened up being cut off at the bottom, so consequently was bug fixing that, the only was to see if I had fixed the errors was to like, check to text area wasn't cut off which it still was, then I would unlike so I could retest, my problem now is I have a confirm button in place.

I understand this is to stop like-jacking but is there anything I can do to stop it? Surely people have to test their stuff to make sure its all working.

any info appreciated.

Jon

nvm I see this will probably get closed, facebook is great in so many respects but try and find out who to talk to regarding issues is ridiculous.

Comment: test with somebody elses page and then switch the id's when you are done testing.